# How to show the delegated `constructor` reference issue in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the example below I noticed the comment "fixes the delegated constructor reference" and I'm curious -how can I show this "not working / then working after I add that line of javascript?

full gist here => https://gist.github.com/getify/5572383

Thank you in advance

```
function Foo(who) {
    this.me = who;
}

Foo.prototype.identify = function() {
    return "I am " + this.me;
};

function Bar(who) {
    Foo.call(this,"Bar:" + who);
}

Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;    // "fixes" the delegated `constructor` reference
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions in javascript are actually objects.  When we create any function `Foo` in Javascript, the interpreter automatically creates a `prototype` property `Foo.prototype`, which is itself an object. The interpreter then creates a `constructor` property on this object which refers to `Foo` itself:

```
console.log(Foo.prototype.constructor);                   // reference to Foo;
console.log(Foo.prototype.hasOwnProperty("constructor")); // TRUE;
```

This same process takes place when we create the `Bar` function.  But later we introduce a difference.  The difference is that we manually overwrite the object at `Bar.prototype` with this code:

```
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

Now `Bar.prototype` has a new object that we created manually. This new object does not have a `constructor` property because it was created by us and not the interpreter:

```
console.log(Bar.prototype.hasOwnProperty("constructor")); // FALSE
```

So `Bar.prototype` does not have its own `constructor` property but `Foo.prototype` does.  Next, imagine that we create an instance of `Bar`:

```
var myBar = new Bar();
```

`myBar.constructor` is an inherited property that does not exist on the `myBar` object.  If we try to access it, the javascript interpreter searches up the prototype chain for the `constructor` property.  It does not find one on `Bar.prototype` because we overwrote that object. The interpreter continues searching and eventually finds the property on `Foo.prototype`. As a result, any reference to `myBar.constructor` will refer to `Foo.prototype.constructor`, which contains a reference to `Foo`:

```
console.log(myBar.constructor); // reference to Foo
```

So this is why we explicitly set `Bar.prototype.constructor` manually, so that when traversing the prototype chain, the interpreter will find a `constructor` property on `Bar.prototype` as it would have if we hadn't overwritten it:

```
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

The end result is more useful behavior on our objects:

```
var myBar2 = new Bar();
console.log(myBar2.constructor); // reference to Bar
```

This issue should not come up often as it is somewhat rare that one would need to check the `constructor` property of an object.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.
Now the question is when, why and in what scenario one would use `constructor` property.

Comment: Why would one ever need to check the constructor property? I have yet to see a practical use case for that property. It is more for proper book keeping than of any actual use, IMHO.